# Eigenvectors in R

Tags: eigenvector

I am running the Eigendecomposition in R and I get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. However, the eigenvectors I get are normalized. I have two questions -

1. Why does R report normalized eigenvectors instead of the non-normalized ones?
2. How can we get the nonnormalized eigenvectors so that we can match the answers in the text?

Thanks and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The eigenvectors form a vector subspace. There's nothing special about any particular element (except zero), and no special way to choose one. You might normalize to make it easier to match up two eigenvectors, but not to make it more difficult.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I transform the normalized eigenvectors that R provides to the non normalized form?

Comment: You can't and you don't need to.